# How to fetch users' details using their email address

Tags: facebook, email, dom-events

I would like to access users' Facebook
 details using their email address which is located in my database that runs via a form-based website designed in HTML and JavaScript.

I was of the opinion that I should be able to do this using JavaScript but I am not sure as to how exactly to go about this.

I hope my explanation is clear in enough and I am looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Facebook's API.  They do not allow you to look people up by email address via the API per their ToS.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you can't query Facebook users by email address. You could get them to grant permissions to your app and then query your own database though.

Comment: Ah, thanks Jamie. Just as a follow up from your last comment - from my understanding of you comment, you are saying I can query my app from facebook? If yes, my other idea was this (if possible) - I have a one to many relationships on some contacts in my database. For example, contact x has a lot of associated contacts linked to him. Can I from contact x's facebook page, send a friend request to all these associated contact if they were allon facebook? If yes, could you point me on the right direction in achieving this?

Comment: If you're wanting to send friend requests to friends of people registered on your app, then, no. Although it *might* technically be possible,  doubt it as it would breach the fundamental principle of Facebook, being that friends should be people you actually know.

Comment: the users to whom you are sending friend requests would have to have already accepted your app.  You may be able to display on your internal contact list which users have a FB connection to them and encourage users to email their contacts who have not connected Facebook and your application.